# convert a cells with "text numbers with blanks" to numbers that can be calculated

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I am an Excel beginner and spent some time to fix this but finally gave up.. 
Highly appreciated if someone could give me an answer.

I have a dataset that contains number-looking cells but those "numbers" do not allow any calculation. I googled and found that those number-looking cells are probably "texts" actually (I guess it is some sort of string format in some programming languages).

Then I found some ways to convert the number-looking texts to real numbers. Including the "Text to Columns" approach --- failed, and the "paste special approach" --- failed.

It looks like it is a combination of two issues. One is that these cells are actually texts, and the other one is that the numbers in these cells end with a blank. Before addressing that, allow me to describe a bit more about my effort to solve this. I also found that the built-in function VALUE() can be used to convert a text to its numerical value. I tried and failed. Then I realise that these number-looking text has a blank space attached at the end! So, I used the built-in function TRIM() to get a new tab without ending blanks for each number-looking cells.

However, when I used =VALUE(B3) in the new tab in which I already used TRIM() function to kill any blanks, I still got error. Could you guys explain why my trials were failed and why the approaches I found by googling were failed too ("paste special" and "text to columns")?

I even tried to follow this post but it failed too... 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741991/how-to-convert-text-to-numbers
Any help will be highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Better share some sample data with us for better understanding,, and for the time being you may try,, the `VALUE` function if you just want that text as a number in a cell. What error you are getting?

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using? I tried pasting a number with several spaces after it into a cell. On Office 365 it seems to automatically convert this into a number. Alsodo you see a green corner (like a photo album corner) on top left of the cells? This would mean you would have a single quote ' before your number in the edit bar.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to mention about the error message. It is #VALUE! error which seems to be quite general.

Comment: @Rajib thanks for the comment. It is Excel 2016. I don't see a green corner on top left of these cells. However, numbers in these cells are left aligned. I read somewhere that real numbers in Excel are usually right aligned.

Comment: I found something weird, if I double clicked on the number-looking cell and delete the number and then key in the same number, that cell can then be calculated!? I don't know why but then at least there is a laboring solution...

Comment: Have a look at this page: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/how-to-correct-a-value-error-15e1b616-fbf2-4147-9c0b-0a11a20e409e. See the section "Problems with spaces and text".

Comment: A common problem, especially if the source of the text is an HTML document (web page), is the NBSP character.  It can be removed by `=substitute(b3,char(160),"")`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Could you please post an answer? I want to select you as the best answer because it works! Thank you so much. I tried to vote up for for comment but I can't find a way. Thanks to comments by others too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common problem, especially if the source of the text is an HTML document (web page), is the NBSP character.  It can be removed by

```
  =substitute(b3,char(160),"")
```

Answer (score 1):

A more general solution might be to extract all numerical characters and let Excel treat the result as a number from the start, so to speak. The following formula extracts only "0-9", "-", and "." although it's pretty obvious how to add others or remove these:

```
=VALUE(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IFERROR(UNICHAR(((UNICODE(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(A1)),1))<>47)*(UNICODE(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(A1)),1))>44)*(UNICODE(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(A1)),1))<58)*1)*UNICODE(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(A1)),1))),"")))
```

So no matter which of the horde of hard to list spaces and "non-breaking" spaces, or any other characters at all, that the data source used for formatting their data, and might even have used to make it harder for you to extract their data into some useful form, no matter, only the digits "0-9", the negative sign, and the decimal point are extracted to the cell with the formula (or into some formula that uses the output directly) and so no matter what they are, they cannot bother you further.

There are half a dozen "usual ways" of approaching this, and apparently the one above worked nicely for the poster, but I know of a dozen characters used, at least, from experience, though since I don't keep a list, it's a new fight each time with the piecemeal ways. Plus, this gets one beyond the situations where `F2-Edit-Enter` and `Paste|Special|Multiply (by 1)` don't work... they SHOULD, but apparently Excel sometimes has stray HIDDEN formatting characters that cannot be edited by users. Doesn't matter, those get left behind too.